# How do I use Retrofit2, RxJava2, Gson TypeAdapterFActory to map Gson correctly?

Tags: android, android-studio, gson

I'm currently using Retrofit2, RxJava2, Retrofit2 RxJava2 Adapter, RxAndroid. FIRST OF ALL, should I be using TypeAdapterFactory to deserialize and serialize my Gson instead of JsonSerializer (I heard the former is faster than the latter)?

My Gson has a very complicated structure:

[Picture of JSON complicated structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqyLw.png)

First, as I mentioned, I am planning on using TypeAdapterFactory. Is this the best performance solution to map all the different cases of the Gson I have? For example, sometimes just "data" dict, sometimes there's an "errors" field, sometimes "data" has just one field under it, sometimes "data" has another complex json data structure

Even still, I have to make Response objects (ComputerResponse etc) that encapsulate the corresponding Computer object (or map all the json fields to the POJO). I don't want to do this mapping every single time a ComputerResponse is returned, or maybe do the mapping once, in order to improve performance. How should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to create one model that it has all fields in the most complete way, you can create your method with this [tool](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).